# Check if subtotal is below 30.00

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping, shopping-cart, free-shipping

I want to create a php rule inside the `/template/tax/checkout/shipping.phtml` template, that checks if the subtotal is below a specific value.

I use a shopping cart rule, to apply free shipping above $30.00.

So I want to display the shipping cost or free shipping inside the cart.
So I need to create a php rule that checks if the subtotal is greater than 30, to display the free shipping or shipping cost.

How can I create that line?

Comment: @QaisarSatti No, it is not duplicate. I already set the shoppingcart rule. My question is how I can display a line inside the cart, that displays if there a shippingcost or the order is delivered with free shipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply put this condition and it will make it work.

```
if(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal() > 30){
  echo "Free Shipping";
}else {
echo "your shipping cost";
}
```